# How to print list of availble networks and connect using python

Tags: raspbian, python, wifi, python-3, connection

I have been search for a couple of hours to find a a tutorial on how to show the  list of available networks and connect to a network programmatically.I don't want to use command line.
I have installed python wifi module but there is no tutorial on how to use it programmatically.

Comment: What is wrong with the tool included in the GUI?

Comment: I want to show the list of networks in a local webpage.

Comment: @ShyamMohan, it's a programming question not a question related to RaspberryPi , i think that's why someone downvoted you. Next time try using stackoverflow for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [here](https://pypi.org/project/python-wifi/)

```
# python2.7
>>> from pythonwifi.iwlibs import Wireless
>>> wifi = Wireless('wlan')
>>> wifi.getEssid()
'romanofski'
>>> wifi.getMode()
'Managed'
```

And [here](https://github.com/pingflood/pythonwifi/blob/master/pythonwifi/iwlibs.py#L683)

```
def scan(self):
    """ Returns Iwscanresult objects, after a successful scan. """
    return Iwscan(self.ifname)
```

So

```
# python2.7
>>> from pythonwifi.iwlibs import Wireless
>>> wifi = Wireless('wlan')
>>> wifi.scan()
```

must work.

You can try to find python lib for specific version using the filters on the PyPI webpage, [for example](https://pypi.org/search/?q=python3+wifi&o=&c=Programming+Language+%3A%3A+Python&c=Programming+Language+%3A%3A+Python+%3A%3A+3.5)

Comment: I'm getting this erron when using 'from pythonwifi.iwlibs import Wireless`


`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "showMap.py", line 59, in <module>
    from pythonwifi.iwlibs import Wireless
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pythonwifi/iwlibs.py", line 113
    except IOError, (errno, strerror):
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: Seems not compatible with python 3.5

Comment: @ShyamMohan, it's work with python2.7 for example ?

Comment: @ShyamMohan, oh yes [it is specified](https://pypi.org/project/python-wifi/): Programming Language
Python :: 2

Comment: Yeah it's working with python2.7. but I'm using python 3.5

Comment: Is there any similar module?

Comment: @ShyamMohan, You have [this good project](https://pypi.org/project/pywifi/) apparently : Python :: 2.7,3.4, 3.5, 3.6, 3.7

Comment: I just found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38190545/python3-wifi-module-returns-object-not-list-of-wifi-networks

Comment: @ShyamMohan, if my answer suits you, please accept it.